# Is there a way to launch an activity even when app is killed in android nougat(API level 24 & 25)

Tags: android

Have tried

1. `val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java) intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) context.startActivity(intent)`
   in a Service class

This works only when the app is in background. Not when the app is in killed state

2. Tried SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

   This will work even when app is killed but only on Android 10+ OS Versions

Any other solution to start an activity from a service particularly in Android 7.0 and Android 7.1.1(API level 24 & 25)? Because from Oreo API level 26, we have foreground service.

Comment: How are you defining "killed state"? "Because from Oreo API level 26, we have foreground service." -- foreground services have been around since API Level 1.

Comment: Killed state means 'App is killed forcefully by removing from recents'. @CommonsWare startForegroundService requires API level 26 right?

Comment: "Killed state means 'App is killed forcefully by removing from recents'" -- that behavior will vary across the tens of thousands of Android device models. "startForegroundService requires API level 26 right?" -- yes. You do not need to use `startForegroundService()` on API Level 1 through 25 to have a foreground service.